# Other Extensions that Provide Enhanced Admin Grids for 1.7.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

does anybody know an extension that is good and works for a product grid in Magento?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html

or

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

it may help you

Comment: Thanks, well I had a hard time fixing it though when I got caught up in an error but now everything is fine.. Thanks Keyur